# How far can you go with the fact that "powers beat logs"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

So whilst doing a limit question, I came to a point where I had: $$y_n=\frac{\log(1+ \frac{1}{n^2})}{n}+\frac{2\log(n)}{n}$$

Obviously the second term is the simple case, and we can straight away say that this part of $y_n$ tends to zero as n tends to infinity since "powers beat logs". However, with the first term, am I allowed to also say that it tends to zero with the only justification being that "powers on bottom beat logs on the top" ?

If I am allowed to do this, is there a stronger description of the rule? i.e. powers beat logs with any polynomial in the brackets of the log. And if I'm not allowed to do this, again I ask - is there a stronger description of the "powers beat logs" rule so one can know exactly when they can use it.

Thank you.

Comment: The top is positive and $\le \log 2$.  Even easier than the second term.

Comment: Note that for large $n,  \log(1+ \frac{1}{n^2})$ is close to $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: "powers beat logs" has nothing to do with the first term

Comment: @zhw How come? It's in the form of a log with a polynomial of n inside it over a power of n on the bottom of the fraction?

Comment: Power-beats-log refers to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n^p} = 0$ for any $p>0$. The second term is on this form with $p=1$, but the first term is not so it's not appropriate to say that it goes to zero due to "power-beats-log".

Comment: OK, I guess it seems that the easiest way to proceed with the first term is say that it's $ \le \log2 $, as André Nicolas said.

Comment: @mathphys No, that's not a polynomial of n inside.

Comment: @zhw Whoops, oh yes, polynomials can't have negative exponents. So what if we had $\log(n+1)$? Does powers beat logs only apply when there's a single $n$ inside the brackets? i.e. can it literally only be used the way that Winther has written it?

Comment: Any positive power of $n$ beats out any $\ln p(n)$ at $\infty,$ where $p$ is a polynomial that is positive for large $n.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n \to \infty \ \log (1+\frac{1}{n^2}) = \frac{1}{n^2} + O(1\frac{1}{n^4})$ using Maclaurin series.

Comment: You  might as well write `=` instead of `~`  here.

Comment: yes good point thanks